# Can I pass a custom string to the 'gx' command?

Tags: vimscript, external-command, netrw

I have a file like this:

```
vi.stackexchange.com
example.com
duckduckgo.com
```

I want to be able to open these sites with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>; this doesn't work because there's no protocol (`http://`) in front of these sites.

I tried to make a script to add the `http://` prefix (this is trivial), but I'm not sure how I can then pass my string to <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>:

```
fun! Goto(site)
    let l:site = a:site
    if l:site !~? '^https\?:\/\/'
        let l:site = 'https://' . l:site
    endif

    " Problem: how to I pass l:site to gx?
    exe 'normal gx'
endfun

nnoremap <Leader>g :call Goto(getline('.'))<CR>
```

I looked at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` to see how it's mapped:

```
if !exists("g:netrw_nogx")
 if maparg('gx','n') == ""
  if !hasmapto('<Plug>NetrwBrowseX')
   nmap <unique> gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
  endif
  nno <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseX :call netrw#BrowseX(expand((exists("g:netrw_gx")? g:netrw_gx :            █'<cfile>')),netrw#CheckIfRemote())<cr>
 endif
 if maparg('gx','v') == ""
  if !hasmapto('<Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis')
   vmap <unique> gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
  endif
  vno <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis :<c-u>call netrw#BrowseXVis()<cr>
 endif
endif
```

I can't call `<Plug>NetrwBrowseX` (AFAIK?) ... Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: The hasmapto() test and <Plug>... stuff permits you to customize; instead of gx, for example, you could have vmap <unique> GX <Plug>NetrwBrowseX in your .vimrc, and GX would be the map to invoke the special-file handler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `gx` mapping is calling `netrw#BrowseX()`, so you could call that at the end of your function, passing in the `l:site` variable you've constructed:

```
call netrw#BrowseX(l:site, netrw#CheckIfRemote())
```

I would also suggest that instead of `getline('.')`, you use `expand('<cfile>')`, which evaluates to the filename under the cursor. This will work when the URL is on a line containing other content as well.

Comment: Thanks; not sure how I missed this yesterday; I was confused by the `<Plug>NetrwBrowseX` (I thought that was the function being called), it's fairly obvious now :-) ... Using `<cfile>` is good to know, but not something I can use here since this is part of a larger script.